# It is possible to find out which font in psd is using gimp? Or using another app on ubuntu?

Tags: css, ubuntu, fonts, gimp, psd

Need to find out which font in psd is, using gimp. It is possible? Or please tell how can i do it maybe with another app on Ubuntu?

Comment: you can also identify font here as well just take the text image and upload. https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/  -- https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem some time ago using Gimp: unfortunatly it rasterizes .PSD fonts, rendering them as images, so if you are looking for some free tools, I've created a [PSD fotn extractor](http://giovannimuzzolini.com/get-psd-fonts/) from [Melitingice Github project psd.js](http://meltingice.github.io/psd.js/).

If you need more than just font info, I've started something more complex [here](http://giovannimuzzolini.com/psd-tools/), with layers and image export.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use App and also browser:
https://avocode.com/